# How can I convert a .img.xz file to .img to transfer it to my SDCard?

Tags: image

I have downloaded [Kali v1.1.0](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download) for my Raspberry Pi 2 from here.
But the file I must transfer to the SD Card is a **.img.xz**, not the **desired .img** one.

I have tried to *unpack* with:

```
$ tar -jxvf kali-1.1.0-rpi2.img.xz 
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file. tar: Child returned status 2tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting no
```

Installing the *xz-utils* package:

```
# apt-get install xz-utils
```

... seems not to solve anything (it was already installed).

Same for:

```
$ tar -jxvf kali-1.1.0-rpi2.img.xz
```

What is the **correct way to extract/convert the .img.xz** file to .img ?

Comment: On Mac `OS X` you can just double click the file and it decompresses on the spot. #ElCapitan

Comment: On Windows, you can use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to decompress `xz` files.

Comment: `tar` is for manipulating [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) files; it is not a compression utility.  But since `tar` automatically decompresses tar files before extracting them, people get confused...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just use the `unxz` program:

```
unxz kali-1.1.0-rpi2.img.xz
```

Note: the original file **will be removed**.  Only the `.img` file will remain.
If you want to keep the original archive, use

```
unxz --keep kali-1.1.0-rpi2.img.xz
```

.

Comment: If you wish to retain the original file, add `-k` or `--keep` to the command.

Comment: For example, `xz -d -k kali-1.1.0-rpi2.img.xz`.

Comment: What about the `-d` flag, @Hydraxan14 ?

Comment: From the `xz` `man` page:  `unxz is equivalent to xz --decompress`.  `-d` is short version of `--decompress`.

Answer (score 44):

You can use `xzcat` and `dd` together.

```
xzcat kali-1.1.0-rpi.img.xz | dd of=/dev/SDCARDNAMEGOESHERE
```

It retains original file.

Comment: This is definitely better than the unxz solution. For storage purpose, you can keep the img.xz as it is.

Comment: it works like a charm! love this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use 7zip. When 7zip is installed you can right click the img.xz file and excract to an .img file. 
Installing 7zip can be as easy as installing applications on linux by using chocolatey. Get it from https://chocolatey.org/
Once it is installed open windows powershell in admin privi's and do 
"choco install 7zip"
other packages can be installed the same way and you can find them using https://chocolatey.org/packages to find some of your favorites. NO MORE DOWNLOAD FOLDER CLUTTER!!! YAY!

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, I tried gunzip on my mac, which is native, and it worked fine:

```
gunzip openhabianpi-raspbian-201804031720-gitdba76f6-crc9e93c3eb.img.xz
```

Comment: This cannot work if the file is really **xz** compressed as its prefix `.xz` indicates. `gunzip` can only uncompress files in gzip format. You have to use `unxz`.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting... 
Well, I've just unarchived it and also etched the image on the sdcard. 
I didn't start the openhabian installation actually to see if the image is valid, but I'll do it next days and let you know the result.

Comment: With unix, file names doesn't matter. You can name a file as you like no matter what type it is. It's possible to name a file with prefix `.xz` but in real it is a **gzip** compressed file. Check the real file type with `file ./filename.xz`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu/Debian, I like to use `unp`.

```
unp 2022-09-22-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img.xz
```

Here is a little summary from its man-page:

> **unp** is a small script with only one goal: Extract as many  archives  as
> possible,  of any kind and from any path to the current directory, pre‐
> serving the subdirectory structure where needed.  Is  a  Do-What-I-Want
> utility  and helps managing several extraction programs without looking
> for needed options for the particular tool or worrying  about  the  in‐
> stallation of the needed program.